# Mac Cannot Boot From External Hard Drive

Tags: linux, hard-disk, macintosh

So I recently purchased a Seagate 4TB External Hard Drive ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B017KE8OG0/ref=psdc_595048_t1_B00HXAV0X6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017KE8OG0)) and decided to put linux on it.  My steps were (on Windows):
1. Converted to FAT32 and MBR (Maybe an issue?)
2. Created an Easy2Boot partition (I tried some others on Mac and Windows but it didn't seen to work).
3. Added a bunch of linux distros.
So this worked fine on my Windows computer and ran like a charm.  However, I would like it if I could run it on my Macintosh computer and (if possible) run it on my Windows without changing anything if I wanted to.  When I plug this into my mac, I can look under the startup disks and the boot options (when you hold down option during boot) and nothing is found.  How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macs can only UEFI-boot AFAIK (you don't say what type you have).
You need to make a .imgPTN file and add it to the Easy2Boot drive.
As a first step - try converting a clonezilla.iso.
Read more about UEFI-booting and watch the YTube videos.

Also, the maximum E2B will support is 2TB (2TB of your drive will be wasted because it does not support GPT partitions). I do not recommend a very large FAT32 partition. I recommend a 137GB NTFS partition for E2B. You can then add >4GB .imgPTN files and .iso files if you wish.